# How to use a price_id in paymentIntent instead of amount

Tags: python, stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

I use the paymentIntent API this way:

```py
intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
    amount=1000,
    currency='eur',
    customer=stripe_customer_id,
    payment_method=stripe_payment_method_id,
    off_session=True,
    confirm=True,
    receipt_email=customer.email,
)
```

I have created a product in the dashboard. The dashboard provides a priceID which looks like this: `price_1LT0RKGPl0rdJavu7TKMB4F7`.

Is it possible in the paymentIntent to use this `priceID` or anything that can be related to my product previously created in the dashboard instead of the `amount` value required in the `paymentIntent`?

Basically, I would like something like this:

```py
intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
    amount=price_1LT0RKGPl0rdJavu7TKMB4F7,
    currency='eur',
    customer=stripe_customer_id,
    payment_method=stripe_payment_method_id,
    off_session=True,
    confirm=True,
    receipt_email=customer.email,
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible, PaymentIntents are a lower level/more custom API that simply take a raw `amount` you pass from your own code.

You can use the Price with other higher-level integrations which make use of your Stripe Price+Product catalogue. They end up creating PaymentIntents indirectly for you, and you would do the payment that way. Any of of these are options:

- Orders https://stripe.com/docs/orders/create-and-process
- Checkout https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout
- One time invoicing : https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration